# Como reescrever / reestruturar JSON a partir de URL externa?

Tags: php, json

Essa é uma dúvida que já tem muito tempo em que penso em perguntar aqui no StackOverflow. Já procurei por toda a internet atrás de uma solução, porém não obtive sucesso. Não encontrei nenhum assunto sobre aqui no SOpt.

> A dúvida é a seguinte: **é possível reescrever, digo (reestruturar) um arquivo JSON externo já existente?**

Imagine que você deseje eliminar alguns objetos que não utiliza, ou então traduzir objetos de alguma API, ou somente torná-lo mais limpo.

Exemplo **Arquivo JSON**:

```
{
  "content" : [ {
    "userId" : 3370,
    "year" : 2015,
    "unity" : {
      "organ" : {
        "entity" : {
          "entityId" : 2102309,
          "name" : "Jack Sparrow"
        },
    "type" : null,
    "lic" : [ ]
  }],
  "numberOfElements" : 1,
  "totalPages" : 0,
  "totalElements" : 1,
  "firstPage" : true,
  "lastPage" : false,
  "size" : 0,
  "number" : 0
}
```

Exemplo - **Saída** - **Arquivo JSON - Reestruturado**: (resultado)

```
[
  {
    "usuarioId": 3370,
    "ano": 2015,
    "entidadeId": "2102309",
    "nome": "Jack Sparrow"
  }
]
```

> Qual a maneira mais eficiente para fazer essa reestruturação via **PHP**?

Estava tentando no PHP algo como isto:

```
<?php
$json_strdoc = file_get_contents("https://site.com/arquivojson"); //Puxa o arquivo

    $objdoc = json_decode($json_strdoc); //Decodificando JSON

   echo "["; //Inicio Colchete

        foreach ($objdoc as $itemdoc){  //Imprimindo elementos individualmente     
            echo "                
  {
    "usuarioId": $itemdoc->content->userId,
    "ano": $itemdoc->content->year,
    "entidadeId": $itemdoc->content->unity->organ->entity->entityId,
    "nome": $itemdoc->content->unity->organ->entity->name
  },
"
   echo "]"; //Fim Colchete

?>
```

Não sou expert em PHP, então estou exemplificando com um código que sei que está errado, mas que fica mais entendido. Não encontrei a forma correta de imprimir o novo arquivo JSON.

Comment: Mas a ideia é ser apenas esse exemplo especifico ? Quais são as regras de transformação ? São sempre as mesmas ?

Comment: Sim, exatamente @Isac =)

Comment: Você vai precisar colocar em array e fazer a saída com json_encode... O resultado sempre será um array de uma posiçao?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você trazer a escrita dessa forma:

```
[
  {
    "usuarioId": 3370,
    "ano": 2015,
    "entidadeId": "2102309",
    "nome": "Jack Sparrow"
  }
]
```

Será necessário você armazenar em array e retornar com `json_encode`. Por exemplo:

```
 $objdoc = json_decode($json_strdoc); //Decodificando JSON
 $retorno = array();
 foreach ($objdoc as $itemdoc){  //Imprimindo elementos individualmente     
     $retorno[] = array(
          "usuarioId"  => $itemdoc->content->userId,
          "ano"        => $itemdoc->content->year,
          "entidadeId" => $itemdoc->content->unity->organ->entity->entityId,
          "nome"       => $itemdoc->content->unity->organ->entity->name
        ); 
  }

 echo json_encode( $retorno );
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: dá uma olhadinha nessa pergunta que fiz: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433782/como-filtrar-e-ordenar-elementos-json-reescritos-com-php