# Como filtrar e ordenar elementos JSON reescritos com PHP?

Tags: php, json

> O script abaixo obtém o arquivo JSON e reestrutura ele em um novo modelo.

```
<?php

$json_strcont = file_get_contents("http://app.tce.ma.gov.br:8889/remessas?enteId=2102309"); //Puxa todas as remessas
$objcont = json_decode($json_strcont); //Decoficando JSON

$output = array();
foreach ($objcont->content as $content) { //Transforma o JSON decodificado em Array
    $item = array(
        "tiporemessa" => $content->tipoRemessa->nome,
        "periodo" => $content->periodo->nome,
        "exercicio" => $content->historicoRemessa->exercicio,
        "dataenvio" => $content->dataEnvio,
        "arquivo" => "http://app.tce.ma.gov.br:8889/remessas/download/" . $content->arquivo
    );
    $output[] = $item;
}
echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); //Imprime o array recodificando-o em JSON

?>
```

[**Antes**](http://app.tce.ma.gov.br:8889/remessas?enteId=2102309) | 
[**Retorno - Novo JSON**](http://buritibravo.ma.gov.br/json/remessas-rreo-rgf.php)

Como ordenar a impressão do novo **JSON** pela data ( `$content->dataEnvio` ) da mais recente para a mais antiga e excluir / ignorar os que não tiverem data, ou seja, `dataEnvio` = `null`?

E como filtrar todos os elementos que contêm o objeto ( `tipoRemessa->nome` ) com o valor ( `RGF - LEGISLATIVO MUNICIPAL` ) e excluir / ignorar no novo **JSON**?

> Não encontrei nenhuma pergunta sobre filtrar e ordenar a saída de um JSON Reescrito.

Comment: E quando `dataEnvio` for `null`? :)

Comment: @LuizFelipe então seu respectivo elemento é ignorado / excluído da lista, pois os que estão `null` não servem. =)

Comment: Acho que vale a pena pesquisar sobre a função `usort` do PHP. Além disso, em relação às datas vazios, é só você não fazer o _push_ (`$output[] = $item`) ao novo _array_ caso a data seja `null` (e qualquer outro critério que você desejar).

Comment: @LuizFelipe você consegue transformar seu comentário em uma resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Não encontrei nenhuma pergunta sobre filtrar e ordenar a saída de um JSON Reescrito.

Não existe esse papo de filtrar o JSON, você escreve já filtrando o objeto, é você quem está controlando o objeto antes de ser JSON, transformar em JSON é a ultima etapa, o que importa é entender o que esta querendo e fazer o uso do básico da linguagem, aprenda o básico, vou por partes para entender melhor:

> excluir / ignorar os que não tiverem data, ou seja, dataEnvio = null?

Mas isso é o principio básico mínimo da programação, usar `if ()`, simples assim:

```
foreach ($objcont->content as $content) { //Transforma o JSON decodificado em Array
    if ($content->dataEnvio) {
        $item = array(
            "tiporemessa" => $content->tipoRemessa->nome,
            "periodo" => $content->periodo->nome,
            "exercicio" => $content->historicoRemessa->exercicio,
            "dataenvio" => $content->dataEnvio,
            "arquivo" => "http://app.tce.ma.gov.br:8889/remessas/download/" . $content->arquivo
        );
        $output[] = $item;
    }
}
```

> E como filtrar todos os elementos que contêm o objeto ( tipoRemessa->nome ) com o valor

Se é você quem controla o JSON que ainda vai ser gerado é `if`, é o básico, é o minimo, se espera um valor exato, então seria dentro do `foreach`:

```
if ($tipoRemessa->nome == 'RGF - LEGISLATIVO MUNICIPAL') {
   ...
}
```

Como são duas necessidades, tem que usar o `&&` para considerar ambas condições:

```
foreach ($objcont->content as $content) { //Transforma o JSON decodificado em Array
    if ($content->dataEnvio && $tipoRemessa->nome == 'RGF - LEGISLATIVO MUNICIPAL') {
        $item = array(
            "tiporemessa" => $content->tipoRemessa->nome,
            "periodo" => $content->periodo->nome,
            "exercicio" => $content->historicoRemessa->exercicio,
            "dataenvio" => $content->dataEnvio,
            "arquivo" => "http://app.tce.ma.gov.br:8889/remessas/download/" . $content->arquivo
        );
        $output[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Por fim, para ordenar você tem a documentação do próprio PHP para arrays (porque como eu disse você trata o objeto, tornar em JSON é depois disso):

- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.array.php

Eu **não posso responder** sobre ordenar, porque em nenhum momento da pergunta você disse como deveria ser a tal ordenação, a não ser que você esteja confundindo ordenação com filtrar, de qualquer forma, você não ordena e nem filtra o JSON, você faz isso é com o objeto (o array), pois é você quem o controla, e para isto você pode usar esta função (que está na documentação):

- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uasort.php

Eu não quero criticar e nem ficar lhe dando palpites pessoais, mas eu não entendo, esse é o básico da programação e você é membro do site a 5 anos, como pode pular os passos básicos? Tudo isso se aprende no começo, se foque em aprender o básico do começo de novo, porque isto vai lhe ajudar a evitar problemas e até códigos exagerados. Você pode até achar que vai tomar tempo, mas não tem como ir adiante sem o básico.

Comment: Guilherme, testei aqui mas tive que colocar `$content->` antes do `tipoRemessa->nome == 'RGF - LEGISLATIVO MUNICIPAL'` no `if`. Consegui ordenar da forma que eu queria já. Só não consegui colocar outra condição. Tentei colocar  `&&` na frente com outra condição, porém não funcionou. Sobre ser membro há 5 anos, passei um tempo afastado, me dedicava mais ao frontend, mas agora estou estudando a fundo backend.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes IF não tem haver com backend, tem if em todo lugar, lógica é independente de "lado" neste caso, a não ser que o seu front se refira ao Adobe XD ou Photoshop. Eu vejo perguntas suas sobre PHP a alguns anos, e está sempre no mesmo estágio, falhando no básico... Essa sua IF tá toda errada `if ($content->dataEnvio && $content->tipoRemessa->tipoRemessaId == '1' && $content->tipoRemessa->tipoRemessaId == '2') {`, como você quer que `$content->tipoRemessa->tipoRemessaId` seja igual a 1 e a 2 ao mesmo tempo? Isso faz sentido pra ti?

Comment: Tentei assim: `if ($content->dataEnvio && $content->tipoRemessa->tipoRemessaId == '1' || $content->tipoRemessa->tipoRemessaId == '2') {` funcionou, utilizando o operador `||` porém a data já não funcionou.

Comment: Exatamente, há alguns anos... porém me afastei por um bom tempo, voltei aos estudos recentemente.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes não se mistura && com ||. Então as perguntas que vc faz sobre PHP a um bom tempo que comete as mesmas falhas desta, mesmo as antigas, que vejo em diferentes anos, foram aleatórias?

Comment: Qual seria a forma correta? =)

Comment: @AlexandreLopes não se mistura && com ||, essa é a forma correta, é saber o que você precisa, aprender o básico... Eu já até respondi outras perguntas, mas não é de hoje que vejo você pecar no básico, e hoje resolvi tentar lhe abrir a mente, mas eu realmente acho que você não esta querendo aprender, você só quer algo pronto, não estou falando por mal, mas eu não apoio em uma comunidade para se ensinar a programa  você ficar pedindo helpdesk.

Comment: Pior que sim, na época eu perguntava só na teoria, agora estou perguntando na prática... admito que descansei, me dediquei a outras coisas... mas estou confiante, tô assistindo muitos videos sobre, estou estudando lógica de programação, mas no php funciona em outras palavras.

Comment: Fiz assim: `if ($content->dataEnvio && $content->tipoRemessa->tipoRemessaId == '1' or $content->dataEnvio && $content->tipoRemessa->tipoRemessaId == '2') {` e deu certo. Muito obrigado por abrir minha mente, consegui desenrolar aqui. Tudo certo. Obrigado.